# Is there a way to speed up this piece of code in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, optimization, multidimensional-array, neural-network, matrix-multiplication

```
Input = rand(32,32,3);
Theta = rand(10,16);


Output = zeros(30,30,3,16); % preallocate
for i = 1:30
     for j = 1:30
          Output(i,j,:,:) = permute(cat(2,ones(1,1,3),reshape(Input(i:i+2,j:j+2,1:3),1,9,3)), [2 3 1]).'*Theta;
     end
end
```

Whew! I know there is lot going on here but maybe there is a way to speed this up. This code breaks down channels of 32 by 32 CMY image Input into 3 by 3 overlapping matrices, reshapes them into vectors, adds 1 and multiplies by the matrix Theta, to get feature maps (of convolutional neural nets) as an output.

Comment: Could you write it in Matrix Form?

Comment: @Drazick what do you mean?

Comment: @ĬnfernalSeraphím There is presumably an equation you're trying to turn into code. What is that equation (in terms of matrices and operators)?

Comment: How big your operation is that you are looking for speeding up the code? The code by itself looks fine. Check the answer by @Rafael

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
Output(i,j,:,:) = permute(cat(2,ones(1,1,3),reshape(Input(i:i+2,j:j+2,1:3),1,9,3)), [2 3 1]).'*Theta;
```

To this:

```
Output2(i,j,:,:) = [1 1 1; reshape(Input(i:i+2,j:j+2,:),9,3,1)].'*Theta;
```

Averaging a thousand loops here, there is a speed up from **16.3ms** to **6.9ms** on the code.